# Why `type(x) == int or float` doesn't work?

Tags: python

```
def distance_from_zero (x):
    if type(x) == int or float :
        return abs(x)
    else:
        return 'Nope'
```

The function is supposed to return the abs of `x` if the input is either an `int` or `float`.
If the input is none of those it should return `Nope`

I don't see what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Nicer solution for your problem is `if isinstance(x, (int, float)):`

Comment: Reclosed to another dupe; the other post was clarifying a case where the statement meant something else entirely; the statement in that post was *correct*, but the OP was asking if it was asking for clarification of the meaning.

Answer (score -3):

You have to use `type(x) == int or type(x) == float`.

Comment: BTW the reason this got downvoted is because the proper response to this question is to close it as a duplicate, rather than re-answer it here.

Comment: Thanks for the note, that makes sense. Just wondered about the downvotes.